# Angular-UI-Bootstrap accordion keeps collapsing right after opening

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am just getting started with AngularJs and I'm making a simple site navigation app that queries an API for values. Currently I'm trying to make an accordion sidebar applet (is that the correct term for a child app of a parent app?) that loads the primary sections, then lists the categories within when the section headers are clicked.

Well I got it to work without throwing an error (yay!) but if I apply the css, then the accordion becomes timid and bashful, only revealing whats inside for less than a second before hiding the contents again. And a lot of times I have to click on the header twice before something happens.

I'm guessing its a problem with Bootstrap because as I mentioned, It's not like that if I remove the css and just have raw html output. Here's my code:

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="navApp" ng-strict-di>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="~/Areas/AngularTest/scripts/app.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="menuController">
        <div ng-include src="'templates/sidebar.html'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Grunt to combine my js files into one `app.js` so here are the separate pieces.

**`scripts/controllers/navController.js`**

```
var navApp = angular.module('navApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngAnimate'    
]);


navApp.controller('menuController', [
    '$scope',
    'navSectionList',
    'navGetCategories',

    function ($scope, navSectionList, navGetCategories) {
        $scope.navSectionList = navSectionList.query();
        $scope.getSectionID = function (event) {

            var sectionID = event.currentTarget.attributes["data-id"].value;
            $scope.sectionID = sectionID;

            $scope.navGetCategories = navGetCategories
                .getResource(sectionID)
                .query();

        };
    }
],
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.oneAtATime = true;
        $scope.status = {
            isFirstOpen: true,
            isFirstDisabled: false
        };
    }

);
```

**`scripts/services/navService.js`**

```
navApp.factory('navSectionList', [
    '$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/navigation/section/list', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }
]);

navApp.factory('navGetCategories', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var service = {
        getResource: function (sectionID) {
            return $resource('/api/navigation/category/' + sectionID, {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
            });
        }
    };
    return service;

}]);
```

**`templates/sidebar.html`**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="Products" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
            <ul>
                <li>New Arrivals</li>
                <li>On Sale</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{section.name}}" ng-click="getSectionID($event)" ng-repeat="section in navSectionList" data-id="{{section.id}}">
            <ul ng-repeat="categories in navGetCategories">
                <li ng-show="categories.pid == section.id">
                    {{categories.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

I don't really understand AngularJs well enough at this point to figure out what is going on. What do you think I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh God I did it again. So it turns out that you gotta be careful about which version of bootstrap.css you are using. If its one that Angular-UI does not support, you'll get all that funny business going on.

Replacing the css with the following helped fix this problem.

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Version 4 was too advanced for ui.bootstrap.